# The Fabric Audience Map is Broken

Tags: crashlytics, google-fabric

Not sure why, but it appears the Audience Geographic Map stopped working for both our Android and iOS projects. Figure this is a service wide issue.

Comment: What is your question, and is it addressed to an admin of the service you refer to, Fabric committers or Fabric users? Are you just looking for confirmation that this thing does not work for others?

Comment: Are we supposed to know what "Audience Geographic Map" is and how to resolve an issue with it within your company ?

Comment: I apologize, when I selected to create a new topic on their help forums it brought me to stack overflow :p  

I'll most likely kill this as they've reached out via twitter.

Answer (score 1):

Fabric has acknowledged the issue and is working to resolve asap.